# Take Full Page Screenshots with Intern JS

Tags: javascript, selenium, intern

I'm pretty new to JavaScript programming when it comes to UI automation and have come from a Java based Selenium background. I'm currently trying to get my head around InternJS and how to use it to take **full page screenshots** of any URL that I wish and on any device. The end goal is to take screenshots of a specific website on multiple devices for manual visual verification purposes and using a Sauce Labs account.

I was able to separate the `takeScreenshot()` functionality into a re-usable method as follows:

```
MyFile.prototype.takeScreenshotAndWriteToFile = function (fileName) {
  return function () {
    return this.parent
      .takeScreenshot()
      .then(function (fileAsBuffer) {
        fileSystem.writeFile(fileName, fileAsBuffer, 'base64');
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
};
```

However when I run this on various devices / browsers via our Sauce Labs account, I am getting the following results:

- Desktop with Chrome and Firefox (latest versions on Windows 10) only takes a screenshot of what's immediately visible in the browser window at the time I make the request.
- The same result as above applies to testing on Mobile devices and Tablets.
- Oddly, Safari Version 11 (on Mac) **does** take a full page screenshot. Same method. Same implementation. Different result.

I'm completely confused as to why something so simple as wishing to take a full page screenshot is proving to be such a complicated issue... could anyone please point me in the right direction as to what I can do to achieve my goal?

Or if anyone knows of a better alternative to Intern JS in this case? I'm open to any ideas / advice at this stage.

Comment: The ability to take a full screenshot is provided by each driver, not InternJs. Taking a full screenshot is not a simple matter, especially when the page is dynamic with fixed elements and when they change once the scrolling starts ([example](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes)). In a validation context the best approach is to take multiple screenshots while scrolling the window and to stitch them together.

Comment: That's what I am achieving right now - basically taking multiple screenshots while scrolling down through the page.

It's just that on smaller devices (such as mobile) with very small screen resolutions, this is taking **a lot** of screenshots.

So the follow up attempt was to try and achieve one larger screenshot which covered everything as manually verifying tens of screenshots isn't ideal either.

Comment: The middle content is usually composed of repeated elements. So taking a screenshot of the top and bottom should be enough to validate the layout.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Florent! I will take all of this on board. Seems I need to alter my approach to this.

Comment: Hi Florent - given you were the first to comment on my question, could you please add a comment that I can mark as "best answer" for you?

I'm happy that you answered my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Florent pointed out, screenshots are actually handled by the driver that's interfacing with the browser (e.g. chromedriver) rather than Intern, which is interfacing with the driver. According to the [WebDriver spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#screen-capture), a screenshot will only be of the viewport, not the full page. The JSON wire protocol (the precursor to WebDriver) is a bit vaguer on the subject. In any case, different browser drivers can and do behave differently in many situations.

Any testing system that uses WebDriver/Selenium to manage browsers (which is most of them, particularly the popular open source ones) is going to be subject to the capabilities of the driver, and may not support this feature out-of-the-box. However, it could probably be implemented in the testing system (higher level than the WebDriver), so it would be worth filing a feature request with Intern (or whichever WebDriver-based testing system you might be using) if it seems worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'm satisfied that Florents answer (and your reassurance of that) is correct so I've abandoned this effort to go "full page".

Thanks for the comment! It was very helpful!